# Error when reading events from kafka with SpecificAvroSerde

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, avro

I got error when reading events from a kafka topic

> 'org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
> deserializing Avro message for id 4494 Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find
> class topLevelRecord specified in writer's schema whilst finding
> reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.'

```
final Map<String, String> schemaMap = Collections.singletonMap(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaServerURL);

final SpecificAvroSerde<VertexTransactionRawEventValue> vertexTransactionRawEventValueAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();

vertexTransactionRawEventValueAvroSerde.configure(schemaMap, false);
KStream<String, VertexTransactionRawEventValue> vertexTransactionRawEventValueKStream =
            streamsBuilder.stream(vertexTransactionRawEventTopic,Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), vertexTransactionRawEventValueAvroSerde));
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdHPY.png)

However when I read events as GenericRecord Type instead of VertexTransactionRawEventValue, I was able to read the events.

```
KStream<String, VertexTransactionRawEventValue> vertexTransactionRawEventValueKStream =
            streamsBuilder.stream(vertexTransactionRawEventTopic);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that a class named `topLevelRecord` doesn't exist on your classpath.

GenericRecord doesn't try to find specific Avro-compiled classes on your classpath to use

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, I was using the wrong serde.